# How to remove drop down menu in Transfer ant-design?

Tags: css, reactjs, customization, antd, transfer

I want to use `Transfer` Component from `antd` but I don't need the `drop down menu` as you can see in the below picture . How can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the only way is through css selection since the component API doesn't have any control over it via props. Put below code in your css file:

```css
span.ant-transfer-list-header-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4122-forked-87p31?file=/index.css)

**EDIT**

It's possible to "change" the menu options by setting the `selectAllLabels` props of the component but you'd have to build the dropdown menu yourself. You'll still have to hide their header dropdown in CSS since you're replacing their menu with your own menu.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Transfer, Dropdown, Menu, Space, Button } from "antd";
import { DownOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const mockData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  mockData.push({
    key: i.toString(),
    title: `content${i + 1}`,
    description: `description of content${i + 1}`
  });
}

const initialTargetKeys = mockData
  .filter((item) => +item.key > 10)
  .map((item) => item.key);

const App = () => {
  const [targetKeys, setTargetKeys] = useState(initialTargetKeys);
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);
  const onChange = (nextTargetKeys, direction, moveKeys) => {
    console.log("targetKeys:", nextTargetKeys);
    console.log("direction:", direction);
    console.log("moveKeys:", moveKeys);
    setTargetKeys(nextTargetKeys);
  };

  const onSelectChange = (sourceSelectedKeys, targetSelectedKeys) => {
    console.log("sourceSelectedKeys:", sourceSelectedKeys);
    console.log("targetSelectedKeys:", targetSelectedKeys);
    setSelectedKeys([...sourceSelectedKeys, ...targetSelectedKeys]);
  };

  const onScroll = (direction, e) => {
    console.log("direction:", direction);
    console.log("target:", e.target);
  };

  const leftLabel = ({ selectedCount, totalCount }) => (
    <Space size={5}>
      <Dropdown
        placement="bottomLeft"
        overlay={
          <Menu>
            <Menu.Item>
              <a>Option 1</a>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
              <a>Option 2</a>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
              <a>Option 3</a>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        }
      >
        <DownOutlined style={{ fontSize: 11 }} />
      </Dropdown>
      {selectedCount > 0 ? `${selectedCount}/${totalCount}` : totalCount} items
    </Space>
  );

  const rightLabel = ({ selectedCount, totalCount }) => (
    <Space size={5}>
      <Dropdown
        placement="bottomLeft"
        overlay={
          <Menu>
            <Menu.Item>
              <a>Option A</a>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
              <a>Option B</a>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
              <a>Option C</a>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        }
      >
        <DownOutlined style={{ fontSize: 11 }} />
      </Dropdown>
      {selectedCount > 0 ? `${selectedCount}/${totalCount}` : totalCount} items
    </Space>
  );

  return (
    <Transfer
      dataSource={mockData}
      titles={["Source", "Target"]}
      targetKeys={targetKeys}
      selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
      onChange={onChange}
      onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
      onScroll={onScroll}
      render={(item) => item.title}
      selectAllLabels={[leftLabel, rightLabel]}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4122-forked-tr7xl?file=/index.js)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although the solution that doesn't make a change in the `display` was more desirable, It also works in my case. 

So, it seems there is no way to customize the menu options too. Do you have any idea to change the menu options (for example add another option or remove an option ... ) or at least change the text?

Comment: @ZahraTalebi yes, it is possible. Please see my edit.